# ランダムな場所をrayであるかどうかを確認させたい

Tags: unity3d

エラーを吐いてしまい動きません、エラーの内容は以下の通りです。

```
error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'raycast.movePosition'
```

どうすれば動きますか？また動いたら正確に動くでしょうか。

```
public class raycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 movePosition; 

    void Start()
    {
        movePosition = moveRandomPosition();  
    }
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {

        void Update()
        {
            Ray ray = movePosition;

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10.0f))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);
            }
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red, 5);
            movePosition = moveRandomPosition();
        }
    }
    private Vector3 moveRandomPosition() 
    {
        Vector3 randomPosi = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7, 7), Random.Range(0, 0), Random.Range(-7, 7));
        return randomPosi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じでうろうろさせたいのであれば、

[image: Wonder.gif]

こういうコードでできます。

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class RayTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float _moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] float _rayLength = 5.0f;
    Vector3 _destination = default;

    void Start()
    {
        MoveToRandomDestination();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, _destination - this.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * _rayLength, Color.red);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, _rayLength))
        {
            Debug.Log($"{hit.collider.name} を検出した。");
            MoveToRandomDestination();
        }
    }

    void MoveToRandomDestination()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        _destination =
            new Vector3(Random.Range(-7, 7), 0, Random.Range(-7, 7));
        Debug.DrawLine(_destination, _destination + Vector3.up, Color.green, 3f);
        StartCoroutine(MoveToDestination());
    }

    IEnumerator MoveToDestination()
    {
        Vector3 direction = _destination - this.transform.position;

        while (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, _destination) > _rayLength)
        {
            this.transform.Translate(direction.normalized * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("目的地に到着した");
        MoveToRandomDestination();
    }
}
```

[unitypackage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhal6guad5i9fc4/87914.unitypackage?dl=1) も置いておきます。